# htaccess RewriteRule subdomain php to html friendly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subdomain called **m.domain.com** and it is pointing to a folder called **/app**.

i want to make a rule in htaccess like:

```
RewriteRule ^a-([0-9]+)\.html$      myfile.php?id=$1  [L]
```

`myfile.php` is in `/app` and `RewriteRule` is not working.

any help ??

---

i already have a .htaccess in root and when i do RewriteRule with other pages it works.

like www.domain.com/a-1234-b-54321.html   it means www.domain.com/myfile.php?id=1234&sub=54321

But it is not working with example that i sent

if i write http://m.domain.com/a-123456.html it goes to 404 page, not found

Comment: Where is the .htaccess file located? root or subfolder?

Comment: Not only where is .htaccess, what is **not** working? Not working can mean a lot of things. What exactly is the result? Do you get an error? Does it do anything? etc. You need to be as descriptive as possible.